# BCEDIT not work in delete at remove UNETBOOTIN at error in install Ubuntu in Windows 10

Tags: code

```
BCDEDIT/DELETE {ed691510-03ba-11eb-b17b-c0e434ee9b0c}
BCDEDIT/DELETE : The term 'BCDEDIT/DELETE' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ BCDEDIT/DELETE {ed691510-03ba-11eb-b17b-c0e434ee9b0c}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The term 'BCDEDIT/DELETE' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

You need to have a space after `bcdedit`:

```
bcedit /delete ....
```

> **BCDEdit Command-Line Options**
>
> The following command-line options are available for BCDEdit.exe.
>
> ```
> BCDEdit /Command[Argument1] [Argument2] ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Operating on entries in a store**
>
> `/delete`     Deletes an element from a specified entry.

Source [BCDEdit Command-Line Options | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdedit-command-line-options)

Comment: I  have put  space but nothing,  there is not find  {ed691510-03ba-11eb-b17b-c0e434ee9b0c} error install Ubuntu.